# reading from a particular tuple onwards from a file in python

Tags: python, file

Using seek and tell is not functioning properly as the tell returns the current position in bytes; I need to get the line number rather the position of file pointer to proceed.

I have a file `glass.csv` and I need to cluster the datasets. Each line in the file contains a number `1,2,3...` like the below:

```
65,1.52172,13.48,3.74,0.90,72.01,0.18,9.61,0.00,0.07,1
66,1.52099,13.69,3.59,1.12,71.96,0.09,9.40,0.00,0.00,1
67,1.52152,13.05,3.65,0.87,72.22,0.19,9.85,0.00,0.17,1
68,1.52152,13.05,3.65,0.87,72.32,0.19,9.85,0.00,0.17,1
69,1.52152,13.12,3.58,0.90,72.20,0.23,9.82,0.00,0.16,1
70,1.52300,13.31,3.58,0.82,71.99,0.12,10.17,0.00,0.03,1
71,1.51574,14.86,3.67,1.74,71.87,0.16,7.36,0.00,0.12,2
72,1.51848,13.64,3.87,1.27,71.96,0.54,8.32,0.00,0.32,2
73,1.51593,13.09,3.59,1.52,73.10,0.67,7.83,0.00,0.00,2
74,1.51631,13.34,3.57,1.57,72.87,0.61,7.89,0.00,0.00,2
142,1.51851,13.20,3.63,1.07,72.83,0.57,8.41,0.09,0.17,2
143,1.51662,12.85,3.51,1.44,73.01,0.68,8.23,0.06,0.25,2
144,1.51709,13.00,3.47,1.79,72.72,0.66,8.18,0.00,0.00,2
145,1.51660,12.99,3.18,1.23,72.97,0.58,8.81,0.00,0.24,2
146,1.51839,12.85,3.67,1.24,72.57,0.62,8.68,0.00,0.35,2
147,1.51769,13.65,3.66,1.11,72.77,0.11,8.60,0.00,0.00,3
148,1.51610,13.33,3.53,1.34,72.67,0.56,8.33,0.00,0.00,3
149,1.51670,13.24,3.57,1.38,72.70,0.56,8.44,0.00,0.10,3
150,1.51643,12.16,3.52,1.35,72.89,0.57,8.53,0.00,0.00,3
```

I need to take some inputs from those tuples having `1` as the last number and save it in another file, (`train.txt`), and the remaining in another file, (`test.txt`). Likewise I need to take certain lines from those having `2` as the last number and append to the first file i.e. `train.txt` and remaining to `test.txt`.

I cannot get the second input but appends the first result itself.

Comment: the above is completely lacking the requirement to place 70% of each into one file & 30% into the other.  Also, does it have to be the first 70%, in which case you need to count them all first, or would having the first 7 of each 10 be close enough?

Comment: Please Go through this link-->archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/…...This is my dataset and it is of this that I mentioned the 70-30 division .Of each tuple ending with 1 or 2.etc..i need to take the first 70 for storing it to train.txt and remaining 30 to test.txt..Also the tuples retrieved subsequently of 2 ,3..as last value on the same 70-30 basis needs to be appended to above mentioned files..Hope this makes my question specific

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for reading a text file is line-by-line. You can just do something like that:

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as f, open('output_1.csv') as output_1, open('output_2.csv') as output_2:
    for line in f:
        line_fields = line.strip().split()[',']
        if line_fields[-1] == '1':
            output_1.write(line)
            continue
        if line_fields[-1] == '2':
            output_2.write(line)
```

Or you can use the CSV module, it's much easier https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Since it is a text field you really should compare the last field with '1', etc. or convert it to an int first.

Comment: Go through this link-->http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data...I would lyk to divide each dataset having 1,2,3,5,6,7 as the last value into two ie first 70% in train.txt file and remaining 30% in test.txt.Once the division and writing is done for 1,next the same procedure is applied for those tuples having 2 as last value ..this time the values should be "appended" to the above mentioned files..Similarly with 3,5,6,7.Can u please modify the above code to work in this way

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, assuming that you have a large file and can not simply load the whole file would be to use 1 file for each to do your sorting.  If it is a small(ish) input file then just load as a comma separated file using the `csv` module.

As a quick and dirty method, (assuming smallish files).

```
data = []
with open('glass.csv', 'r') as infile:
   for line in infile:
      linedata = [float(val) for val in line.strip().split(',')]
      data.append(linedata)

adata = sorted(data, key=lambda items: items[-1])
## Then open both your output files and write them in the required fields.
```

Comment: but I need the values to be stored in two files ie train.txt and test.txt..The dataset having 1 at last is taken and is divided on the ratio 70:30 ie 70 for training and 30 for testing..Similarly is the case with tuples ending with 2,3,5,6,7 but their divisions are to be appended to the above mentioned file and not overwrite..Thanks in advance

Comment: This is my input dataset link>-->archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/…